# Can anyone tell me how to install collections package in python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am getting below error while installing collection library in python 3.9

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement collections (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for collections

Answer (score 2):

`collections` isn’t a PyPI package that you install with pip.

It’s a module in the standard library that’a always present: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

You just have to import it.